# Dynamic column name in Oracle

Tags: oracle, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically set a column header.

Here the example:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(cars) AS (('cars_from_year_') || year)
FROM peaple 
WHERE car = 'GM'
AND Date BETWEEN (year || '0401') AND (year || '0430');
```

The `year` should be for ex. 2012 and change (i.e. this being dynamic) for every year (2013,2014,...).

I know the call `select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') from dual` but not how to implement it the select statement above?

Comment: See this: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=678873

Answer (score 3):

Column names must be known at compile time. You obviously want to use dynamic column names so you will need to postpone the compilation until the actual execution. There are several ways to do this: [`DBMS_SQL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sql.htm#ARPLS68176), [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BHCEBBAI) and [`REF CURSOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#sthref549) for example.

Here's an example with `REF CURSOR` and `SQL*Plus`:

```
SQL> var x refcursor
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_year NUMBER := 2012;
  3  BEGIN
  4     OPEN :x
  5        FOR 'SELECT ''This is the year ''||:year AS "Year ' || l_year || '"
  6               FROM DUAL'
  7        USING l_year;
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print x

Year 2012
--------------------------
This is the year 2012
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with crosstab. Take a look [this](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.com/2005/09/pivot-and-crosstab-queries.html) and [this](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/oracle-11g-cross-tab-report-using-pivot-and-unpivot-operator/) for querying crosstab on oracle

Answer (score 0):

Try the pivot comands now available in 11g otherwise pl/sql is your only option as per Vincent Malgrat.

Nice question!